# What is the longest reasonable distance one may expect to ride on a comfort bike?

Tags: long-distance, cruiser

I ride a 2011 Trek Navigator 1 with 7-speed derailleur.  Purchased in August of 2011, I've tried to ride as often as possible.  My longest rides have been approximately 12 miles in length.  I've equipped the bike with SKS fenders and a rear rack.  I'm getting to the point where I'd like to start taking longer rides, maybe 10 or miles each way.  Is this sort of riding unfeasible on a "comfort" bike?

Comment: With this bike you can ride 14 hours in a single day, or go perhaps ride 200km in a single day (seriously!), without the risk of anyone reasonably question if the bike is appropriate or not. For the distance you pointed, no problem AT ALL, even ten times that. It depends only on fitness, nice road, and nice mood. But you have to grow this distance small steps each time, depending mostly on your age. Go for it!!

Comment: No reason (other than the lack of low gears in the mountains) that you couldn't ride that bike across the US.  You may discover, eg, that you'd do better on a "road" saddle, or that the heavy tires are slowing you down a hair, but all those things come in due time.

Comment: I voted to close. There are way too many variables as to "longest reasonable distance". Looks like a chat/opinion question to me.

Comment: The question was not intended as a chat/opinion question.  I am new enough to bicycling this was a real question.  By all means close the discussion if you wish.  The answers have been extremely informative to me.

Answer (score 14):

I would argue that there is no limitation on distance the biggest limitation you will have will be on: Speed and Comfort over time.

### Speed

Comfort bikes arn't made to go fast.  They are designed to be ridden around in a leisurely way.  Variables limiting speed include:

- Aerodynamics - you are sitting as upright as possible
- % of your speed/strength you can use while pedaling - Mountain bikes are designed so that the rider has good control and can soak up bumps.  Road bikes are designed to be maximally aerodynamic and to allow the rider to use their leg muscles effectively.  Comfort bikes are designed so that you will be comfortable sitting on the seat.  I have always found that when riding a comfort bike I cannot use my muscles nearly as effectively.  On a road or mountain bike it is much easier to use your upper body to provide leverage to your legs out of the saddle.
- Weight - shouldn't have an effect on a constant speed but when speeding up you will notice the weight of your bike.  You will also notice the extra weight when climbing.  In all other situation weight shouldn't make any difference.

### Comfort over time

Road bikes and to a lesser extent mountain bikes are made to be comfortable for long period of time for more dedicated riders.  Just looking at the seat as a case study we find: wide seats are comfortable immediately but after sitting on it for an extended period of time:

- You will experience chaffing
- You will possibly need to rock your hips to reach around the seat to push the pedals
- You cannot use your entire body properly which may lead to injured muscles
- You cannot soak up bumps at all which may lead to a sore/stiff back

### Conclusion

- If you goal is to cover distance get a new bike.  You will go double your distance.
- If your goal is to get a good workout and you are not experiencing discomfort keep your current bike and go further.

Comment: I agree you should get the most of your bike before considering to change it for another. You can reposition yourself, use narrower tires, swap some minor components... I like to ride comfort bikes and they can be efficient if you set up a more "sporty" cockpit. +1

Comment: @heltonbiker Good points.  The tires he has on there (assuming he hasn't changed from the stock) look slick -> pretty fast.  He could swap in a narrower seat and maybe lower his handlebars but it maybe better to start looking for the next craigslist special.

Comment: +1

The limitation isn't so much distance as it is speed and time. Your speed will not be as fast as on a more traditional non-racing road bike. Your comfort will be limited for longer efforts due to the unsuitability of the bike for those sorts of tasks. Ride longer distances until you get to the point where you're uncomfortable; then you'll know.

Comment: I have a similar bike and have had no problems riding it on 70 KM tours. Spend a minimal amount of money for a narrower saddle, and possibly a stem and handlebars to lower handlebars and you should be fine.  These can be picked up used for next to nothing.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  A friend is giving me the Razesa touring roadbike he bought at Madrid in the mid-Eighties.  It'll be awhile before we can meet up, though.  Hoping for greater distance in less time, which really does seem to be the point of my question.  These answers have gone a long way to clarify that for me.  Again, thanks.  C.

Answer (score 8):

It's totally reasonable to ride such distances (and even much longer) on a Navigator.

I have a 2003 Navigator back in Poland. It was my "return to cycling as an adult" bike. I've done many 30+ mile rides on it in rolling terrain. I don't think it would be much fun on a super hilly ride (due mostly to the bike's heft) but even that is doable. As people have mentioned, you can't be in a hurry -- the bike is not meant to go fast.

Ride regularly, increase your mileage slowly (10% per week is an oft-quoted figure) and enjoy your bike.

Comment: Also my return to bicycling as an adult bike.

Comment: I've read the 10% per week increase not only for cyclists, but also for distance runners.  It's good advice. Don't forget to listen to your body, though.  Something starts to hurt, you may want to dial back the distance increases.  As a reference, my mother started cycling on a schwinn cruiser adult tricycle.  First time out, (16 months ago) she could barely go around the block. Now she's doing 8 miles everyday, rain, wind, or brutal houston heat, she's out there.

Answer (score 5):

One of the first rides I did with my (now) wife was a 60 mile course, which she rode on a Mountain bike. It was easy to know she was with me, because the wide knobby tires made enough noise to hear from a distance. The rolling resistance had to be sky high. She wasn't happy with the ride, but she finished.

After that ride we immediately shopped for a new bike.

The point is that it's not the bike that is the limitation, it's you in combination with the bike. If it's not working out you'll know pretty quickly, and the attempt won't kill you. Try it and see.

Comment: I will probably get a narrower saddle as others have suggested and continue to try longer rides until I can get a road bike.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> My longest rides have been approximately 12 miles in length. I've equipped the bike with SKS fenders and a rear rack. I'm getting to the point where I'd like to start taking longer rides, maybe 10 or miles each way. Is this sort of riding unfeasible on a "comfort" bike?

A twenty mile ride is definitely not unfeasible based on what you describe. You're already doing 12 miles, so adding 8 more shouldn't be a problem, depending on your fitness level and the terrain. (Terrain will be a big factor. A "reasonable distance" on flat terrain may very well be "unreasonable" on very hilly terrain.)

Anecdotally speaking... I know several people who regularly ride 20 to 50 miles on comfort bikes. I also know a few who would find 10 miles challenging. The "longest reasonable" distance is a bit subjective, but based on the description of your goal, you should be fine.

And like heltonbiker mentioned, you may want to use narrower tires and possibly swap out your seat.

I would suggest experimentation. Gradually add distance and time on the bike, and your body will let you know.

Good luck.

*A quick note... I was just in the local bike shop at lunch picking up a tube and took a look at "comfort" bikes. My impression is that if I wanted to ride a "comfort" bike for relatively long distances... I would change the seat to something more like a road bike seat. The stock seats look fine for maybe 2 or 3 hours, but beyond that, I'd really want a skinnier seat. And depending on the stock tires, I might want to change those as well.*

Answer (score 2):

74 years old fairly new at biking (2 years)with a recent hip replacement. Been riding a Townie beach cruiser for 35 miles and I am working to reach my 50 miles goal. The Townie is fine for any distances in my opinion and you feel safer because of the easy dismount.Recently also purchased a Townie fat tire bike for long distances. In my opinion it takes a bit more effort but it is worth it because of the comfort.
Roy G.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Sounds like great riding. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My 2010 Trek Navigator 3.0 is a quality bike capable of being ridden as far as your rear will stand.  My longest single day ride was 50 miles on this bike.  The gearing on the Trek is quite Low having a similar 34 tooth cassette as some mountain bikes and most certainly lower geared than most of the road bikesI've examined.

In 2010, I put 1500 miles on it and upgraded to a Surly LHT after I convinced myself that biking was going to remain a part of my life.  I am 6'2 and ~230 so I am a big guy, but the bike did not care.  Trek builds three versions of the Navigator old ones are 100 - 300 and the newer ones are 1.0 - 3.0 with the 3 series having better components, ie, shifters, seats, hand grips.

The problem for long rides with this bike is also it's advantage. According to bike shop employees, most Comfort customers ride less than 10 miles at a time and the upright position is very comfortable.  Road and touring bikes distribute the weight over the seat and the bars and while it took my arms awhile to stop aching from the change on the LHT, eventually you find yourself quite comfortable in that non-upright position.  Must be why they build so many that are NOT upright. The simple point is that after 10 miles my hands and my rear hurt and that means stopping more frequently than you or your friends will like on a long ride. Several 'fittings' impacted my wallet but not hands or my rear.

Personally I see the Hybrids in the comfort class, but with skinny tires and better shifters. You still ride them upright though. To be fair though, my Daughter-in-Law ~45, can ride a century on her Hybrid, and I only wish I could keep up with her for 5 miles, much less a 100.

My Navigator served me very well.

Answer (score 1):

I have ridden my Electra Townie for multiple rides between 30-50 miles over the last month and have determined that distance does not work for me on that bike.  A comfort bike is less than ideal for longer distances due to the seat, the posture, the inability to ride faster than 12-13 mph and a frame that does nothing to absorb the road rattle.  For me, once I crossed the 20 mile distance it was time to look at other bikes.  Longer distances are certainly not impossible (I have sure done them) but the "comfort" tends to wane at mile 20 or so.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on multiple factors, such as weight, level of fitness, etc. I've been using comfort bikes for about 8 years, and while I don't regularly go over 10 miles a day ( my most common daily mileage is 4 miles ), I've done at least ten 50 milers in 6 of the years I've been riding, and one 90 mile ride once. My top speed, depending on different factors, can range from 15 mph all the way to 20-24 mph, though 10-12 is what I usually ride at. And this is a bike bought at Walmart, too. I'm on dialysis now, due to my kidney transplant rejection ( I've always had heart issues, and eventually became diabetic ), but I've done two 20 milers since. I've never had a geared bike, and am hesitant to buy one since I don't know whether it would help me much. But if anyone can let me know if a geared bike ( multiple gears, not single gear ) would help, that'd be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The first part of your answer is useful, but at the end you segue into a question of your own.  If you have a question you'd like answered, you should ask it, but bear in mind it needs to be clear what you're asking for.  (What you mean by "would help," for instance; help in what way?)

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm new to this. I meant help in that it make cycling easier, allowing me to cover greater distances.

Answer (score 0):

I am 68 years old with medical conditions that preclude running , walking, or riding a road bike. But, amazingly I can ride a bike in an upright position all day. I started out with a huffy and got up to thirty miles. Bought an aluminum frame cruiser from bikes direct and re assembled it to professional standards and regularly ride 55 miles. I am about to a 68 mile ride to commemorate my birthday. I will be riding an old raliegh aluminum that I put a comfort seat and 36" bars. I am running road tires. It is not about what other people think, it is about how a bike fits you and your condition.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of comfort bikes is that your back and ass will take all of the load, whereas your hands will take approximately zero percent of your load. After your ride, you will find that some body parts are aching and some aren't.

By making the riding position lower, so that part (but not too much) of your load is carried out by your hands, after the ride all of your body parts would be aching at about the same level. Because part of the aching would go away from other body parts to your hands, the ride you are comfortable doing would be longer.

Also a comfort bike has usually handlebars that resemble flat bars but are slightly curved towards the rider. These curved or flat handlebars aren't ideal if much of your load should be carried by your hands, because the hand position is so unnatural. Long distance riders prefer drop bars where you hold your hands in a position similar to the position you hold your hands on a car steering wheel.

Also a comfort bike has an unaerodynamical riding position so you travel slower. Because of this, a ride of one hour on a comfort bike is shorter than a ride of one hour on a road bike.

I don't think the effect on ride length would however be major. A long ride is a long ride still and requires you to be fit, no matter what bike you are using. Also many road bikes have so low handlebars that non-fit riders might not be comfortable doing even a 5-mile ride!

Before I installed drop bars on my bike, on my comfort-ish bike (with a handlebar very slightly curved towards the rider, and derailleur gears), I was easily able to ride 40 km with no major problems.